# Flexbox doesn't work in IE 10

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hey there i am using a flexbox grid on a gallery to let the first div occupy 2 columns and make it all responsive.
It works all fine just in IE10 Flexbox goes crazy and the 2 Column Div goes super large, i cant figure out why.

http://codepen.io/HendrikEng/pen/wzRQNJ

CSS :

```
.c-showcase {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
.c-showcase::after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.c-showcase-quote {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.c-showcase-item {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
.c-showcase-item::after {
  clear: both;
  content: '';
  display: table;
}

.c-showcase {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.c-showcase-block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.c-showcase-quote {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="c-showcase">
  <div class="c-showcase-block">
    <div class="c-showcase-quote">
      <h2 class="c-showcase-quote__title c-showcase-quote__title_outline_black">BLA BLA BLA</h2>
      <p class="c-showcase-quote__content">blablalbl</p>
    </div>
    <div class="c-showcase-item">
      <div class="o-image-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-showcase-item">
      <div class="o-image-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-showcase-item">
      <div class="o-image-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-showcase-item">
      <div class="o-image-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-showcase-item">
      <div class="o-image-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-showcase-item">
      <div class="o-image-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="c-showcase-item">
      <div class="o-image-container">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x350">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Parse your CSS through [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/). It will add the necessary rules.

Comment: I tried it , doesn't work unfortunately , i updated the copepen with autoprefixer.

Comment: Have you also tried using `flex-basis` on children instead of `width`? Also give `max-width` a shot.

Comment: You're right in your title. Flexbox doesn't work (well) in IE10: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex You should look for the large number of bugs there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `float:left;` on flex children. That's box model. What you probably want is:

```css
.c-showcase-block {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.c-showcase-quote {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.c-showcase-item {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

Prefixed version here:

```css
.c-showcase-block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.c-showcase-quote {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 50%;
     -moz-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 50%;
          flex: 0 0 50%;
}
.c-showcase-item {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;
     -moz-box-flex: 0;
      -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
          flex: 0 0 25%;
}
```

Wrap it in a media query if you don't want it applying at all widths. `flex` is a shorthand property for `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` and `flex-basis`, in that order.